# How to parse json from file in sdcard

Tags: json, flutter

I am new to flutter and application development. I am making an offline dictionary app that reads a json file from the phone memory and parse it in the app container. I am able to do it by bundling the json in app, but facing problem in getting the file from phone memory. This is the code for reading the file: -

```
Future<Null> fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    _list.clear();

    final response = await rootBundle.loadString("${widget.value}");
//    final response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/abvn.json');
    final data = jsonDecode(response);
    setState(() {
      for (Map i in data) {
        _list.add(Posts.formJson(i));
        loading = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Here ${widget.value} gives the absolute path of the json in phone memory. the commented line is for parsing json bundled in the app, which is working fine. The error I'm getting: -

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: /storage/emulated/0/Download/test2.json
E/flutter ( 5719): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
E/flutter ( 5719): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5719): #1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:67:33)
E/flutter ( 5719): #2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:162:56)
E/flutter ( 5719): #3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:293:23)
E/flutter ( 5719): #4      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:162:27)
E/flutter ( 5719): #5      _dicState.fetchData (package:abvnsearch/main.dart:173:39)
E/flutter ( 5719): #6      _dicState.initState (package:abvnsearch/main.dart:204:5)
E/flutter ( 5719): #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4640:58)
E/flutter ( 5719): #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter ( 5719): #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 5719): #11     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5830:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 5719): #14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter ( 5719): #15     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter ( 5719): #16     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter ( 5719): #17     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter ( 5719): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 5719): #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5830:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 5719): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5830:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 5719): #26     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter ( 5719): #27     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter ( 5719): #28     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter ( 5719): #29     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter ( 5719): #30     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:11)
E/flutter ( 5719): #31     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter ( 5719): #32     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 5719): #34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5830:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #35     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 5719): #37     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5830:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #38     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter ( 5719): #39     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter ( 5719): #40     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter ( 5719): #41     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter ( 5719): #42     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter ( 5719): #43     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter ( 5719): #44     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:11)
E/flutter ( 5719): #45     ComponentElement.m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
As log file said, I assume file is located in `Download` folder

```
Unable to load asset: /storage/emulated/0/Download/test2.json
```

Step 1: Add permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Step 2: Add package `ext_storage` and `permission_handler` notice version is `4.4.0`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  ext_storage: any
  permission_handler: 4.4.0
```

Step 3: Request permission and access file with the following code

```
void _fetchData() async {
    String path = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    print(path);
    File file = await File('$path/test2.json');
    String contents = await file.readAsString();
    print(contents);

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void requestPermission() {
    PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    requestPermission();
    super.initState();
  }
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ext_storage/ext_storage.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _fetchData() async {
    String path = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    print(path);
    File file = await File('$path/test2.json');
    String contents = await file.readAsString();
    print(contents);

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void requestPermission() {
    PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    requestPermission();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _fetchData,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answering,
I am able to read the file with this code using File.readAsStringSync(), however I'm still not able to figure out how to pass it to the jsonDecode(). I'm getting failed assertion error when I try. I guess null is being send to the decode function.

Comment: need to reproduce, please provide full json string in your file.

Comment: My bad. I had a mismatch in the json object keys. Thanks it worked.